# How to connect data-mining with machine learner process

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I want to write a data-mining service in [Google Go](http://golang.org) which collects data through scraping and APIs.

However as Go lacks good ML support I would like to do the ML stuff in Python.

Having a web background I would connect both services with something like RPC but as I believe that this is a common problem in data science I think that there is some better solution.

For example most (web) protocols lack at:

- buffering between processes
- clustering over multiple instances

**So what (type of libraries) do data scientists use to connect different languages/processes?**

Bodo

Comment: One solution which goes in the direction I am looking for is [fluentd](http://fluentd.org).

Comment: Are you interested only in libraries available within Google Go?

Comment: @Hack-R if it is a more complex protocol which requires some heavy logic I would prefer that a library would be available in Go but I would even more prefer if the library would be a available for other languages too. What do you think of a message queue like [nsq](http://nsq.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% if a message queue library will be the right tool for this job but so far it looks to me so.

With a messaging library like:

- [nsq](http://nsq.io)
- [zeromq](http://zeromq.org)
- [mqtt](http://mqtt.org) (?)

You can connect different processes operating on different environment through a TCP based protocol. As these systems run distributed it is possible to connect multiple nodes.

For **nsq** we even have a library in Python **and** Go!

Answer (score 4):

The `Data Science Toolkit` is [a powerful library](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/) (or collection of libraries, technically) which are available in a number of languages. For instance, I use the implementation called `RDSTK` in R.

In the case of your preferred language, Google Go, there's [a list](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/Projects#Web_Libraries) of web-related libraries here which looks very useful.

Comment: The `Data Science Toolkit` is very interesting but not what I am looking for. I am looking for some high performant stream based protocol which allows me to stream (and buffer) data from n data-miners to m data-processors.

Answer (score 2):

If your only motivation for using Google Go is webscraping, and you want to do you ML in python, I would recommend the following stack:

[Python requests for scraping data](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

[MongoDB for caching data](http://www.mongodb.org/) (MongoDB's page oriented format makes it a natural home for storing JSON objects commonly returned by APIs)

[pymongo for interfacing python and mongodb](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/)

[scikit-learn for doing your machine learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/)

This all happens in python and you can extend it multiple processors with 
[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) or to multiple nodes with django

Comment: This is a *pure* python solution?

Comment: No, using mongodb for caching.  I think Mongodb is written in Java if that's what you mean?